# Not able to use all features on my Android phone

Tags: feature-request

I have been trying to ask and answer questions through my mobile phone, using UCBrowser or Chrome, but the editor doesn't show up as on desktop.

Please fix this as people mostly use mobile phones and don't use the app. Adding code requires the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, which is not available on a phone.

Comment: I don’t think UCBrowser is on the list of supported browsers, have you tried with the Android stock browser?

Comment: What do you mean the editor doesn't show up as on desktop. Chrome (on Android at least) has the explicit option to show the desktop site. And I would be surprised if "mostly people use mobile phones" on this site. As for supported browsers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: it ask me to use ctrl + k while answering code can you please tell how to use that on android

Comment: You can't. You can select the text and press the "{}" button though

Comment: if I select a text and then press a button it will be over written

Comment: So switch to the app that's made for the platform, or use the site from a desktop.

Comment: That's why I've requested for the feature as This is a informative platform and must be available with least resources to the user.

Comment: Android’s stock browser is supported since 4.0?

Comment: In the end it's all markdown anyway. Format your text as you see fit by inserting the correct characters or spacing yourself. That is, if none of the earlier options are possible for you. But there is nothing stopping you from posting. It may just be a bit harder.

Comment: Am I wrong to expect a well working platform to be working everywhere equally and with all the features.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be wrong with that assumption. They have only 150 developers, not 150,000.

Comment: Many of us don't have all the resources all the time .So many a time this will hinder the growth of the users.

Comment: Please add a feature to donate if user  found something helpful, This way Stack overflow can support more developers

Comment: @ISHANMAHAJAN that's a separate suggestion (and not, in my view, a very good one; not least because *people might donate again this month* is not a good reason to hire someone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the editor doesn't show up as on desktop

It does *if you switch to desktop mode*; showing mobile devices a mobile-optimised page (at least initially) is a pretty common pattern. Either use your browser's functionality to *"request desktop site"* or click the *"full site"* link in the footer.

> Adding code requires the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, which is not available on a phone.

No it doesn't, you can click the `{}` button while you have your code selected, or manually add four spaces to the start of each line.

> people mostly use mobile phones and don't use the app

I'm not sure either part of that is true, and more importantly not sure we want it to be. Mobile devices aren't ideal for submitting what we hope will be high quality, long-lived content. Adding more functionality to the mobile site does not seem to me to be the best use of the developers' time, particularly given that they have made freely-available mobile apps.

Comment: Yeah that's true most of the users use mobile browser so I thought of requesting to get this feature available everywhere.That would've been great.

Comment: @ISHANMAHAJAN you have numbers to back that up or are you just going to keep asserting it? I for one use the iOS app a lot for browsing, but write the overwhelming majority of my posts on the desktop site.